# Properties of functions of the form $f^{(n)}=I$?

Tags: functions

Take as example a function $f:\{0,1,2\}\to \{0,1,2\}$ defined as

$$f(k)=k+1-3\left \lfloor{\dfrac {k+1}3}\right \rfloor $$

we can see that $f(0)=1,\ f(1)=2,\ f(2)=0$, having so $(f\circ f\circ f)(k)=f^{(3)}(k)=k$, giving us the relation $f^{(3)}=I$. This means that it takes $3$ applications of $f$ from any starting position to get back where we started. The general form of these functions is

\begin{equation}
f^{(n)}=I \tag{1}
\end{equation}

It's easy to show that if $f$ is a function with property $(1)$, then $f^{-1}=f^{(n-1)}$ holds, so ${f^{-1}}^{(n)}=I$ is true too.

and one of it's special cases (when $n=2$) are the [involutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)), functions of the form $f^2=I$, but what about functions whose *period* (in this case $n$) is greater than $2$? What can we say about them? It seems reasonable to think of a function with the property that $f^{(\infty)}=I$, where you get back to where you started only if you apply the function infinitely many times (I don't have an example, but it seems interesting). What are it's properties?

Comment: Are you interested in any particular domain for $f$?

Comment: I'm not sure you'll find any sort of compendium on the shared properties of these functions. If you're interested such functions on a finite discrete domain, then their actions reduce to studying permutations and their orders. For example a permutation has order $n$ iff the LCM of orders of its cycles has order $n$.

Comment: @AlexS No, anyone will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some interesting (miscellaneous) facts about these types of functions. They aren't really about permutations, as your answer was, but they regard functions from reals to reals.

- All continuous involutions from reals to reals are in the form $g^{-1}(-g(x))$, where $g$ is a continuous, bijective function from reals to reals.
- The only continuous function $f:\mathbb R\mapsto\mathbb R$ with $f^{\circ 2n+1}(x)=x$ for all $x$ is the identity function, where $n$ is odd.
- All continuous involutions from reals to reals, other than the identity function, are strictly decreasing.
- This function satisfies $f^{\circ n}(x)=x$:
  $$f(x)=\frac{x\cos\frac{2\pi}{n}-\sin\frac{2\pi}{n}}{x\sin\frac{2\pi}{n}-\cos\frac{2\pi}{n}}$$
  however, notice that it is not continuous.
- No continuous involution from reals to reals other than the identity function has a continuous half-iterate.